# New view doesnt render and automatically falls back to default view

Tags: view

This is the first time I am seeing this behavior. I created a view "My Test" in the document library. The default view is "Active". After creating a very simple view (none of the stuff checked or filter or group) when I try to toggle to the new view it automatically shows the default view and completely ignores the new view (although in the url is has /forms/My Test.aspx). Please suggest what could be wrong. I spent 2 hours and couldn't figure this out. VERY STRANGE......

Comment: What if you set a new default view and delete the old defaul view?

Comment: have you migrated this list from any other enviroment?

Comment: The list was migrated from 2010 instance by Sharegate. I dont want to delete the working views because it's production and what if the new view doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you open your new view URL while appending `?contents=1` at the end? For example: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SampleSite/Lists/Cities/AllItems.aspx?Contents=1`.

When you do it, can you see any suspicious script webparts? or Content Editor Webparts? If you do - simply remove them. Or at least close them. Chances are all your new views have some kind of a script webpart injected by default.

[image]

Comment: how did you know this? lol there was a another webpart and set to No for open on page. i deleted that web part and now i can create new views. thanks again

Comment: "how did you know this?" - gut feeling. :)